# Publishing API in WSO2 ESB from WSDL

Tags: wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

I can see [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Publishing+a+WSDL) that I can publish a WSLD like Proxy Service in WSO2 ESB.

But, I want to publish an API from a WSDL. Is it possible to do that in 4.8.1?

Answer (score 1):

[WSO2 API Manager](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/) allows you to publish an api from a WSDL. If your soap service is accessible from internet, you can easily try this using [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud).

[This tutorial](https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/Publish+and+Invoke+a+SOAP+API) shows how to do it in cloud. But, its also valid for the standalone product too.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. You cannot create an ESB Rest API from a WSDL or WSDL url as you can create 'WSDL Based Proxy'. But if you want to call the backend SOAP service through an ESB Rest API, that is possible. Follow [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Configuring+Specific+Use+Cases#ConfiguringSpecificUseCases-EnablingRESTtoSOAP) guide for SOAP to REST conversion with an API.