# WSO2 ESB - Api to Soap transformation

Tags: api, soap, wso2, esb

I would like to expose an API (REST) on ESB that traslate the request to a SOAP service.

My Api is definined in this way :

```
 <api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="__test" context="/mytest">

   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{symbol}">
      <inSequence>

         <property name="symbol" expression="get-property('uri.var.symbol')"/>

         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
                <ser:getQuote  xmlns:ser="http://services.samples" xmlns:xsd="http://services.samples/xsd">
                <ser:request>
                        <xsd:symbol>$1</xsd:symbol>
                </ser:request>
            </ser:getQuote>

            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('symbol')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>

         <log level="full"/>

         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <wsdl service="SimpleStockQuoteService" port="SimpleStockQuoteServiceHttpEndpoint" 
                    uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

But when i invoke the url with http://:8280/mytest/WSO2 I heve this error on console

```
<soapenv:Reason xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">
The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/SimpleStockQuoteService.SimpleStockQuoteServiceHttpEndpoint/WSO2?request= and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
</soapenv:Text>
</soapenv:Reason>
```

Because the esb append the **WSO2** part of the request to URL.

How I can solve this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Configuring+Specific+Use+Cases#ConfiguringSpecificUseCases-EnablingRESTtoSOAP) guide for achieving this. Note that the soap action header should be added as follows and endpoint is different.
`<header name="Action" value="urn:getQuote"/>`

Find the complete solution API below,

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="__test" context="/mytest"><resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{symbol}">
  <inSequence>
     <property name="symbol" expression="get-property('uri.var.symbol')"/>
     <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
           <ser:getQuote xmlns:ser="http://services.samples" xmlns:xsd="http://services.samples/xsd">
              <ser:request>
                 <xsd:symbol>$1</xsd:symbol>
              </ser:request>
           </ser:getQuote>
        </format>
        <args>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('symbol')"/>
        </args>
     </payloadFactory>
     <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
     <log level="full"/>
     <header name="Action" value="urn:getQuote"/>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService" format="soap11"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence></resource></api>
```

If you want to use the WSDL url directly, you can achive this using [WSO2 API Manager](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/) and it can be easily tried in [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud/). There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499054/publishing-api-in-wso2-esb-from-wsdl/38509492#38509492).